# "Mettere la porta a padella": what does that mean?

Tags: idioms

**How the questions arose**

Doing more research on [this closed question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8476/una-strofa-di-una-canzone-come-interpretarla), I found other versions of the song, and I just bumped into [this site](http://scambiofigu.forumcommunity.net/?t=35734112), where, among lots of other songs, there is said version of said song, with `Tegnu la porta aperta / La mettu a padiduzza` translated to `Tengo la porta aperta / La metto a padella`.

**Questions**

What does it mean to "mettere la porta a padella"? How commonly and where is this expression used in Italian?

**Note**

@RiccardoDeContardi has commented contributing [this link](https://tinamannelli.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/una-canzone-un-caffe-e-un-saluto/). I also saw that but didn't pay too much attention as that translation is not accurate (e.g. "Ed iu, capu d'amuri, lu cori m'avvampò" + the following verse is all rendered as "gli uccelli cantano in amore"). I've been working on cracking the song for a long time now. You can find all my findings on [my blog post](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/07/vinni-la-primmavera.html) about it. In particular, other versions have "a vanidduzza" instead, which has two possible interpretations, one of which (my choice) is "a fessurina". This suggests a meaning for the expression, but I'd like to be sure, and also to know how this expression came about.

**Update**

Signed in to that forum and sent messages to the poster of the translation enquiring about this. In the process of matching the videos there to the versions on [Sicilian Wikipedia](https://scn.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si_maritau_Rosa) I discovered this new bit:

> Rapi la finestra,
>   Talìa pi tterra e mari
>   O veru amuri tò
>   Ancora hav'a 'rrivari
>   Tu si' tantu bedda
>   'Un ti disperari
>   Chi la speranza è
>   Sempre l'ultima a muriri.

A bit off-topic in this post, but I wanted to post it somewhere other than that chat.

In any case, I'm waiting for that user to come online and possibly reply to me.

Comment: I find here https://tinamannelli.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/una-canzone-un-caffe-e-un-saluto/ a translation; according to it, "Tegnu la porta aperta, la mettu a padiduzza" can be translated into "tengo la porta accostata" (slightly opened). No idea where this expression comes from.

Comment: I suspect you're right: it is vanidduzza and not padidduzza. Padiduzza with a single d is unlikely, since *padella* becomes *padedda* or *padidda*. Possibly someone transcribed the song and made a mistake.

Comment: Have you tried asking whomever made this translation?

Comment: @DaG I generally avoid signing up when I don't know how fast it is and I have no guarantee it will be useful. Now that I saw it takes two clicks thanks to facebook, I have signed up to the forum, BUT I cannot seem to find a "reply" button to reply to the post about that song.

Comment: @LSemi Yeah, I totally agree to the single "d" being a mistake, definitely must be double. Concerning the "transcribed the song" part, I am more cautious because none of the videos I could find of the song have those lyrics, which seem to have been conjured from thin air by a few sites. A great number of versions are to be found online, with varying numbers of verses, wildly varying text, and the forum even has a video with a different tune! Most of what I found is summed up in [my blog post on this song](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/07/vinni-la-primmavera.html)…

Comment: …and on [the Sicilian Wikipedia page about this song](https://scn.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si_maritau_Rosa), which I personally edited to include different versions of the text.

Comment: @DaG Messaged the poster just now. Waiting for them to come online and possibly reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my knowledge, *vanidduzza* is indeed the correct spelling (double d).

In this context, I believe "apru la porta a vanidduzza" means "I leave the door half-open" - IT: "Socchiudo la porta" . This meaning is also reported in the [dictionary](https://books.google.ch/books?id=vBs9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA430&lpg=PA430&dq=vanidduzza%20dizionario%20siciliano&source=bl&ots=nl7ZE_gfXd&sig=pIetGxs7roA-YE6ZLFHnKH_uryI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5prqqr_3VAhWGuhoKHQq-CPcQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=vanidduzza%20dizionario%20siciliano&f=false):

> [image: screenshot of Google Books dictionary entry for "vanidduzza"]

However, it seems that the original text also from [another source](http://karahidden.blogspot.com/2013/06/canzoni-popolari-siciliane.html) reports the term *padiduzza* , never heard of it (at least not used in a real-life discussion) and also not found in the Sicilian dictionary I pointed to in the previous link here above.

Comment: It seems that all sources with this version of the song have "padiduzza", along with "pegni" (which is definitely supposed to be "peni") and "lacrimme", where the geminate "m" is just nonsense and the ending -e is not Sicilian. I guess that, up till someone reports a meaning for this expression with "padidduzza" (or "padiduzza"), I will accept that this is just an error and "a vanidduzza" should be read here.

Comment: The dictionary supports that the double d is the correct spelling, and that "padidduzza" is the diminutive of "padedda", meaning "pan". Nothing about this idiom "a padidduzza".

Comment: «Ah, un'ultima cosa!» (cit. Lt. Columbo). Since I've been working on this song for like [ages](https://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/07/vinni-la-primmavera.html?showComment=1503829272163#c5009402623654754416), could you give me your two cents on the "notturna/atturna" issue explained [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8476/una-strofa-di-una-canzone-come-interpretarla)? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the question is now deleted. I guess you can read the explanation on the blog post linked to in my comment and comment on that post?