# "E io, capo d'amore, il cuore mi s'è infiammato": what does "capo" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, idioms, regional

As a sister to [this question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/mettere-la-porta-a-padella-what-does-that-mean), we have another strange expression in [this translation of the Sicilian folk song "Si maritau Rosa"](http://scambiofigu.forumcommunity.net/?t=35734112):

> E io, capo d'amore, il cuore mi si è infiammato.

The general meaning should be that the singer has fallen in love. However, I don't see how the sentence is structured. The last part is quite clear, but the first part? What is "capo" ("head" or "boss") doing there? Is this perhaps just a mistranslation based on imitation of the Sicilian (in which case the sentence structure is off-topic as it is Sicilian and not Italian) or is this a valid sentence in some regional Italian? I mean, I'd expect at least "E a me" instead of "E io", because the subject is "il cuore"… unless "capo" is being used in some verb sense, but then the punctuation is wrong! Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently, both this and the other question are not about Italian after all, but about some random, incorrect words written by someone on the Internet...

Comment: @DaG Yes and no. Both questions are about "some random, incorrect words [etc]", but since the words are in Italian, the question is still about Italian. Broken Italian, but Italian nonetheless. This question is solved, so if broken Italian is considered off-topic, it could be closed. The other one, however, is still not 100% sure in its answer. There could still be a very local usage of that expression somewhere in Italy. We will probably never no for sure, but it should not be closed (unless a source is found with that version of the song but "vanidduzza": then the conclusion is…

Comment: …wrong text… but no, even then, the expression might exist, just not in the song).

Comment: Actually, made-up Italian (*capo d'amore*, *porta a padella*) is not Italian. It is as if somewhere on the Internet someone translated “cellar door” as *cella d'oro*, and then I came here and asked what is a *cella d'oro*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation you report is not accurate.

The expression "capu d'amuri" in the original text (in Sicilian):

> ed iu, capu d'amuri, lu cori m'avvampò

can be translated to: "all'inizio di" (at the beginning of), meaning 'at the beginning of my love life'.

Anothe example of usage of 'capu' as meaning of 'beginning' is in the Sicilian proverb:

> Avùstu, rijùstu capu ri ‘nvernu giustu - IT: *Agosto riottoso è l’inizio dell’inverno*.

or

> Capu di l’annu saluti e dinari, pensaci bonu a chiddu c’ha fari - IT: *Ogni inizio di anno, pensa bene a cosa devi fare*

Comment: I will tell the poster of the translation about this :). About the proverb: the punctuation doesn't really convince me. Isn't _rijùstu_ referred to _Avùstu_? As in, "A/The riotous August is the true (giustu) beginning of winter"? If so, that comma is out of place and should be either removed altogether or at most placed after _rijùstu_.

Comment: Spelling nitpick: "c'ha fari" is a contraction of "c'hai a fari", and should therefore be spelt with a circumflex to mark the contraction, i.e. "c'hâ fari".

Comment: Here is the source I used for proverbs: https://tanogabo.com/proverbi-siciliani/

Comment: Since you seem to know Sicilian better than me, could you take a look at [this](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/mettere-la-porta-a-padella-what-does-that-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1) too? Maybe there is an inaccurate translation there too. Also, do you know if «apru / la porta a vanidduzza» means «I open the door on the small road», «I slightly (i.e. making a small slit) open the door», or it can mean both? Thanks.

Comment: The meaning I know is 'slighly open the door'. Posted an answer to your question there.